# unable to use arrow keys to shift, instead increases and reduces brightness

Tags: linux

yesterday while i was using my laptop to read a pdf document, i do not know what happened suddenly, i tried scrolling dowm using the arrow key but it was not worworking rather it increased brightness. i taught it was a minor problem but since then i am unable to use my arrow keys. keys like page down do not work correctly also, it rather backwards a song instead of moving to next page. i have tried pressing the fn key, shift f11 and other combinations to no avail. the worst   thing is that it behaves same in bios. i have tried an external keyboard and it works just fine. my laptop is aspire E1-470P-6659. Thanks

Comment: Those arrow keys double as brightness and sound controls when used with the Fn key on the bottom left side.  The PgUp and PgDn keys also have multiple functions.  It sounds like maybe the Fn key is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The standard tools to modify key associations in Xorg are [xev](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xev) and [xmodmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap).

`xmodmap` is the real tool: it is invoked as

```
 xmodmap filename
```

(I put this into my `.bashrc` file) and `filename` (this is most commonly `/home/YourName/.xmodmap`)  contains a list of mappings in this form:

```
keycode 133 = 4
keycode 135 = dollar
keycode 127 = Escape
```

As you can see, since I have three broken keys on my laptop's keyboard, I have re-assigned their *functions* (4, dollar, Escape) to three little-used keys, identified by keycodes 133, 135, 127.

How do I know which keycodes correspond to a given Xorg keymap key? I use `xev`: after the invocation, you can see, as you press each key, a `Key Press/Release event` for every key you touch; immediately below, the `keycode` of that key is identified. That' s what you need to put in `.xmodmap`.